# Class `Call __ instance as first argument error` Tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am making a Tkinter text editor and I am having some trouble with classes. I have made a class with all my functions in it and a class with my mainloop. The root window opens up fine but when press the save button I get the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: unbound method saveas() must be called with F instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I have looked at this and this example but can't figure out what is going wrong. 
What is my problem?

Below is my short code that illustrates the problem.

```
from Tkinter import *
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("PyText")
        self.m1=Menu(root)
        self.fm=Menu(self.m1, tearoff=0)
        self.fm.add_command(label="New", command=self.saveas())
        self.fm.add_command(label="Open", command=self.saveas())
        self.fm.add_command(label="Save", command=self.saveas())
        self.fm.add_command(label="Save as...", command=self.saveas())
        self.fm.add_command(label="Close", command=self.saveas())
        self.fm.add_separator()

        self.fm.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
        self.m1.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.fm)
        self.editmenu = Menu(self.m1, tearoff=0)
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Undo", command=self.saveas())

        self.editmenu.add_separator()

        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Cut", command=self.saveas())
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Copy", command=self.saveas())
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Paste", command=self.saveas())
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Delete", command=self.saveas())
        self.editmenu.add_command(label="Select All", command=self.saveas())

        self.m1.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=self.editmenu)
        self.helpmenu = Menu(self.m1, tearoff=0)
        self.helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index", command=self.saveas())
        self.helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=self.saveas())
        self.m1.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=self.helpmenu)

        root.config(menu=self.m1)


        self.t1=Text(root)
        self.t1.config(width=90, height=40)
        self.t1.grid()
    def saveas(self):
        self.filewin = Toplevel()
        self.e1=Entry(self.filewin)
        self.e1.grid()
        self.button = Button(self.filewin, text="Save", command=self.save)
        self.button.grid()

    def save(self):
        with open(self.e1.get(), "w") as f: # this instance variable can be accessed
            f.write(self.t1.get('1.0', 'end')) # added self.t1 above, and start/end


root = Tk()
app = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building your application wrong. Take the root Tkinter object-building code out of that class. You'll need a class that contains things for your Tkinter object. If you want more classes for other kinds of objects, that's fine. As it is, you're calling `F.saveas` as a class method with no argument, and it's expecting `self`, which is an instance of class `F`, which you don't have because you never instantiated it.

```
from Tkinter import *
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self, root):
        # root.geometry("100x100") # this will make your app window tiny -
        # I've commented it out for now but you'll need to look into it
        self.b1 = Button(root, text="save", command=self.saveas)
        self.b1.grid()
        self.t1 = Text(root) # added a Text widget
        self.t1.grid()
    def saveas(self):
        filewin = Toplevel()
        self.e1=Entry(filewin) # make this an instance variable
        self.e1.grid()
        button = Button(filewin, text="Save", command=self.save)
        button.grid()
    def save(self):
        with open(self.e1.get(), "w") as f: # this instance variable can be accessed
            f.write(self.t1.get('1.0', 'end')) # added self.t1 above, and start/end

master = Tk()
app = Main(master)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have edited my code now to include my full code because doing what you did created more errors.

Comment: @JonahFleming - What errors did you get with that? When I changed all the `command=self.saveas()` to `command=self.saveas`, it seemed to work fine.

Comment: I'll try it but I got all of the menu items running their command at the start of the program.

Comment: @JonahFleming - That's why I changed all the `command=self.saveas()` to `command=self.saveas` as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks that's been really useful +1